# Ember.js outlet not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I'm currently learning ember.js and I'm stuck with a very basic problem: I can't find a way to render a template inside another one using outlets. These are the files I have:

application.handlebar

```
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
            <a class="brand" href="#">App</a>
            <div class='nav-collapse collapse'>
                <ul class='nav'>
                    <li>{{#linkTo 'application'}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
                    <li>{{#linkTo 'posts'}}Posts{{/linkTo}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='container' id='main'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='span12'>
                <div class='page-header'></div>
                {{outlet}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

posts.handlebars:

```
    <ul>
{{#each controller}}
  <li>
  {{title}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

posts_routes:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

       return App.Post.find();
    }
});
```

router.js:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('posts',{ path: '/posts' }); 
    this.route('application',{ path: '/' }); 
});
```

Here is what happens: when I load the application, the page is currently displayed with the nav bar and an empty white page. Clicking the "Posts" link shows the posts template, but the nav disappear as if the posts template replaced the whole "application" template. 
Can you help me figure out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Internally ember use an `ApplicationRoute`, I think that using `this.route('application',{ path: '/' });` is causing conflict.

So just remove the `this.route('application',{ path: '/' });` and all will work.

If you need a home/initial page you can create a `index.handlebars` template, because ember automatically create a `this.route('index',{ path: '/' });`. And change `linkTo 'application'` to `linkTo 'index'`, to get the expected behavior.

Please give a look in that fiddle to see this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/HpmwB/

Comment: I saw your fiddle and it works, but it doesn't work in my case. I still get the same behaviour in which the "posts" template replace the entire page (the navbar disappears). Is there some other details I'm missing? I wrote my app using this as a reference: https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts

Comment: Just removing this.route('application',{ path: '/' }); worked for me. Do you get some error in console?

Comment: No error at all, I got a "Transitioned into posts" in the ember console (chrome), but no error at all. Maybe the fact that I'm using rails as a framework is somehow conflicting with that, but I actually can't figure out how.

Comment: It seems that when I click on "Posts" in the navbar, the template is replacing rails' yield instead of ember's outlet. Does this give you any hint?

Comment: All templates are loaded when the ember app start. So if you click in the "Posts" link, and no request is send to rails, rails isn't the problem. I think.